# Path properties in Cypher

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a following graph in Neo4j

`(id:5,t:e)<--(id:4,t:w)<--(id:0;t:s)-->(id:1,t:w)-->(id:2,t:b)-->(id:3,t:e)`

now I search paths from nodes with `t:s` to nodes with `t:e` such that only white-listed nodes with `t:w` are in-between.

So ideally i need a query to return only (0)-->(4)-->(5) but not (0)-->(1)-->(2)-->(3).

EDIT: i have forgotten to mention that paths may have variable length: from 0 to potentially infinity. It means that I may have an arbitrary number of "t:w" nodes

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Working just with the information that you have provided above you could use

```
MATCH p=({t:'s'})-->({t:'w'})-->({t:'e'}) RETURN p
```

Of course if an `s` could link directly to an `e` you will need to use variable length relationships matches.

```
MATCH p=({t:'s'})-[*0..1]->({t:'w'})-[]->({t:'e'})
RETURN DISTINCT p
```

**EDIT - Paths of any length**

```
MATCH p=({t:'s'})-[*0..1]->({t:'w'})-[*]->({t:'e'})
RETURN DISTINCT p
```

To match a path of any length use the `*` operator in the relationship path match. It is usually best to put some bounds on that match, an example of which is the `*0..1` (length 0 to 1). You can leave either end open `*..6` (length 1 to 6) or `*2..` (length 2 to whatever).

The problem with this is that now you cannot guarantee the node types in the intervening nodes (so `t:"b"` will be matched). To avoid that I think you'll have to filter.

```
MATCH p=({t:'s'})-[*]->({t:'e'})
WHERE ALL (node IN NODES(p)
   WHERE node.t = 's' OR node.t = 'w' OR node.t = 'e' )
RETURN p
```

**End Edit**

You should introduce labels to your nodes and use relationship types for traversal though as that is where Neo/Cypher is going to be able to help you out. You should also make sure that if you are matching on properties that they are indexed correctly.

Comment: i have forgotten to mention that paths may have variable length: from 0 to potentially infinity. It means that I may have an arbitrary number of "t:w" nodes